# Exception caught in Sentry, Error {} //hidden/ in y@webkit-masked-url

Tags: javascript, safari, sentry

As a beginner to Sentry and web dev and debugging issues, some of the errors Sentry is picking up are completely baffling to me, including this one. Our web app seems just fine at the URL that Sentry is saying there is an error at. I'm not familiar with our app using anything related to `webkit-masked-url`. Is it safe to ignore this type of error?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This particular set of mysterious errors has been asked about on [Sentry's GitHub](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/discussions/5875), and they reference [a WebKit issue](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=246010).

According to the comments there, they are caused by an error coming from a Safari browser extension, and can safely be ignored, or [filtered](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/configuration/filtering/#decluttering-sentry).